# Hybris SmartEdit : Rotating Images component not displaying any fields under content tab

Tags: components, sap-commerce-cloud

I am using 6.4 version of Hybris. Added a banner carousel using Rotating Images component (assigned 3 banners to rotating images component).

This component is allowing to edit banners through WCMS edit mode, but in smart edit not displaying any editable fields under content section.

Can you anyone please help me with this ?

[image: Attached screenshot for reference]

Comment: I think this about smartedit capabilities. I haven't find time for testing it in 6.5. Did you try 6.5?

Answer (score 2):

The rotating banner component is not editable even in Hybris 6.7, something SAP has to bring in next set of Smartedit fixes